# Issue with Chrome.ExecuteScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Currently I am using the following code to inject an alert statement into a webpage that prints out a variable I pass in. The script goes as follows:

```
  //Inject statement setting the variable "count" in the webpage to 5
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {
       code: 'count = 5;'
  }); 

  //Inject the script that simply alerts the variable count (alert(count);)
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {
       file: 'inject.js'
  });

  //Inject statement setting the variable "count" in the webpage to 5+1
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {
       code: 'count++;'
  }); 

  //Inject the script that simply alerts the variable count (alert(count);)
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {
       file: 'inject.js'
  });
```

Ideally, I am hoping for a result that alerts "5" then "6." However, the webpage only alerts "5" in both statements, despite me increment the variable "count" in the code. Am I misunderstanding something about chrome.tabs.executeScript, or am I overlooking a simple bug?

Comment: I would encourage you to rethink your design.  Four separate injections (and the same file twice) doesn't smell right.  At the least, `inject.js` should listen for a passed message that would trigger its alert.  Or this entire comment could be moot, because your actual code is significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is an asynchronous call, that means after you call `chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {code: 'count++;'});`, the value of `count` may have not been updated, so the result would either `5` or `6`.

[`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) has a callback, which is called after the JavaScript has been executed. You could wrap your method inside that.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {code: 'count++;'}, () => chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, {file: 'inject.js'}));
```